# Small group proof

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group with $g^3h=h^3g$ and g,h $\epsilon$ G. Show that gh=hg for all g,h $\epsilon$ G

Please help me with this it is driving me mad, I keep getting to

$g^2=h^2$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is $g^3h=h^3g$ true for *all* $g,h\in G$?

Comment: Yes sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Let $e$ be the neutral element. Let $g \in G$, then $g^3 = g^3e=e^3g = g$. It follows $g^2 = e$ for all $g \in G$.

Now let $g,h \in G$. Then $hg = (gh)^2hg = ghghhg = ghgg = gh$.

Comment: Or more easily $hg = h^2hg = g^3h = g^2gh = gh$.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Show that $x^2=1$ for all $x\in G$.
2. Show that if $x^2=1$ for all $x\in G$ then $gh=h^{-1}g^{-1}$ for all $g,h\in G$.
3. Conclude that $gh=hg$ for all $g,h\in G$

(By $1$ I mean the identity element.)